# Lock dimension scale of child meshes in Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, mobile, graphics, 3d, blender

I am building a mobile app in Unity that allows the user to scale objects in all three dimensions (currently using LeanTouch). This all works fine, but obviously when you scale the parent gameobject everything scales in that dimension. I would prefer to only allow certain meshes contained within the gameobject to actually scale, based on the dimension that is scaling.

For instance, if I have a table, and the user wants to increase the width of the object on the fly (i.e. scale in the X direction), I want the top of the unit to scale, but the thickness of the individual legs remains the same. Right now if you scale the width, the legs themselves increase in thickness.

[image: Leg Thickness Scales]

This image illustrates the issue. As the table is scaled wider, so too are the legs. I would like for the leg B width to stay the same as Leg A, despite the table top "stretching" in the X direction.

These models are made with separate meshes for each component, so I'm not trying to do this to a single mesh.

Is there a way to indicate (or within scripts) that a mesh or gameobject can only scale in two dimensions (for instance the table legs can scale in Y and Z, but not X)? I believe this is called "Plane Locking" in Blender.

Right now I'm using Blender to import a DXF, which I'm converting to .obj or .fbx, however I'm a complete noob at it.

Thanks for any suggestions

Comment: I'm not familiar with unity but the scale should be three values for x,y,z. But consider another approach, while scale might be the first thought for changing size, look at moving vertices instead. If you had an armature bone on the right and assigned it the 8 leg verts and 4 right tabletop verts then as you moved it left/right the table would get bigger/smaller but the whole leg would stay the same width.

Comment: You could use `Mesh.bounds.SetMinMax(V3)` for every individual `SubMesh` on the main mesh. I also believe you could define the exact vertices for each mesh.

Comment: I had thought about the vertex strategy both of you suggested, but I'm not very familiar with how to create them (are they included in the FBX, or generated in Unity?) and how to programmatically control them. I will do some research on this because "rigging" the furniture models is an interesting idea. Thanks!

Comment: @Kevin You do not need to create anything. Meshes are generated when a model is created and come with the model when you import it in Unity. You can access all the meshes + sub-meshes on a particular model. Hence the ability of editing the model/mesh itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you writing a simple script that anchors one object to another in a specific position, like this:

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEditor;

[ExecuteInEditMode, DisallowMultipleComponent]
public class Anchor : MonoBehaviour
{
  public Transform target;
  public Vector3 localPosition;

  void Update()
  {
    if (target == null) return;
    transform.position = target.position - transform.TransformVector(localPosition);
  }

  void OnDrawGizmos()
  {
    if (!enabled) return;
    var pos = transform.TransformPoint(localPosition);
    Gizmos.color = Color.red;
    Gizmos.DrawSphere(pos, HandleUtility.GetHandleSize(pos) * .05f);
  }
}
```

I also suggest you to do an object hierarchy similar to this:

[image]

It is advisable that the stretchable object and the anchored object to be siblings with a common parent.

With this, you can transform the table top as much as you want the the legs will remain attached to the position of the anchored objects (that should be childs of the strechable object). If you want a transformation to be applied to both the objects (scaling in the z direction, for example), just transform a common parent. The example is in 2D but it works for 3D too.

[image]

Comment: @Kevin so, did you apply this suggestion? Did this answer help you? If yes, you can mark this as "accepted", so it'll be easier for other people with the same issue to find the solution.

Answer (score 0):

Two easy approaches to this problem are : unparent your gameobjects before you scale the parent (move them to a temporary parent, scale the parent and move tham back). Alternatively you can apply an inverse scale to all the children. The two are roughly equivalent. Have in mind in no case the side 'legs' of your combined object will stick to the sides, in 2D you could use RectTransform class for that, but in 3D I think you'll need some extra steps to achieve that.

Comment: So I have attempted this strategy (temporarily unparenting, reparenting) but I don't know how to tell the legs to update their position to the correct location.

I had also thought about the inverse scaling the children. I may give this a try. One concern is the scaling will occur around the origin, which means the legs may not align "flush" with the outer edge of the tabletop, since the center of the gameobject has had the scaling applied to it.

Comment: your concerns are valid, depending on your case you may need to contain the necessary logic in a script, and do the scaling using that logic (i.e. specifying table parameteres and placing the legs where they should be)